# MySQL error no. 1045

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I am working on a college project, I installed MySQL Server 5.4.
When I create a new connection, it gives a error,

```
MySQL error number 1045
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password: YES)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct password (or no authorization if root's password is not set).

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally set it up with an unknown root password, read up on the skip-privilege-tables configuration flag and how to use it to recover from the situation.